# Group by in Pandas based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe

```
|phone_number|call_date|answered| attempt|
|123        | 13thJune| 1 | 1 |
|234        | 15thJune| 0 | 1 |
|234        | 15thJune| 0 | 2 |
```

I want to perform a groupby and take out the max date of answered. i.e If the call is not answered which is 0 , then max date of answered should be blank.

```
df.groupby(['phone_number'])['Call_Date'].max().reset_index()
```

only when `answered is > 0` else this groupby should give me a `blank`

How do I achieve this?

expected df

```
phone_number | max_call_date 
123 | 13th June
234 | Nan
```

Comment: What is output if second `answered=1` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First idea is filter out rows with not `0` in `answered`, aggregate `max` and add filtered `phone_number` like `NaN`s by [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html):

```
df1 = (df[df['answered'].ne(0)]
          .groupby(['phone_number'])['call_date']
          .max()
          .reindex(df['phone_number'].unique())
          .reset_index(name='max_call_date'))
print (df1)
   phone_number max_call_date
0           123      13thJune
1           234           NaN
```

Or replace `call_date` to missing values if `answered=0` and then aggregate `max`:

```
df1 = (df.assign(call_date = df['call_date'].mask(df['answered'].eq(0)))
         .groupby(['phone_number'])['call_date'].max()
         .reset_index(name='max_call_date'))
print (df1)
   phone_number max_call_date
0           123      13thJune
1           234           NaN
```

Last idea if need set `NaN` if at least one value `answered=0` and minimal value of column `answered=0` is:

```
df1 = df.groupby('phone_number', as_index=False).agg({'call_date':'max', 'answered':'min'})

df1['max_call_date'] = df1.pop('call_date').mask(df1.pop('answered').eq(0))
print (df1)
   phone_number max_call_date
0           123      13thJune
1           234           NaN
```

EDIT: For correct maximal datetime from strings is necessary convert column to datetimes:

```
df['call_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['call_date'].str.replace('st|nd|rd|th',' ',regex=True), 
                                 format='%d %B')


df1 = (df[df['answered'].ne(0)]
          .groupby(['phone_number'])['call_date']
          .max()
          .reindex(df['phone_number'].unique())
          .reset_index(name='max_call_date'))
print (df1)
   phone_number max_call_date
0           123    1900-06-13
1           234           NaT

df1 = (df.assign(call_date = df['call_date'].mask(df['answered'].eq(0)))
         .groupby(['phone_number'])['call_date'].max()
         .reset_index(name='max_call_date'))
print (df1)
   phone_number max_call_date
0           123    1900-06-13
1           234           NaT

df1 = df.groupby('phone_number', as_index=False).agg({'call_date':'max', 'answered':'min'})

df1['max_call_date'] = df1.pop('call_date').mask(df1.pop('answered').eq(0))
print (df1)
   phone_number max_call_date
0           123    1900-06-13
1           234           NaT
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
df = df.groupby('phone_number').apply(lambda x: x[x['answered']!=0]['call_date'].max()).reset_index().rename(columns={0: 'max_call_date'})
print(df)
```

`Output:`

```
   phone_number max_call_date
0           123      13thJune
1           234           NaN
```

Comment: For performance better not filter in `groupby.apply`

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
(df.groupby('phone_number', as_index=False)
   .agg({'call_date':'max', 'answered':'min'})
   .assign(call_date=lambda d: d['call_date'].where(df['answered'].eq(1)))
   .drop('answered', axis=1)
 )
```

Output:

```
   phone_number call_date
0           123  13thJune
1           234       NaN
```

Comment: Question - do you not see my answer, which is really similar?

Comment: In fact no, I'm typing on phone which is both slow and doesn't update the other answers automatically like on computer. I'll UV you ;)

Comment: I was surprise, because obviously not do it ;)

Comment: @jezrael out of curiosity what are you doing in life? You seem to spend a **lot** of time on SO ;)